# Pandas counting how many times a value has been counted in a Group by

Tags: python, pandas

I hope my question doesn't sound like a tongue twister.

I have a table with 2 columns, one column (let's call it "customer_ID") is the customer identifier, and the other columns (let's call it "Date") is the date of the purchase of said customer. For example:

| Customer_ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 807x | 2010-2 |
| 807x | 2010-3 |
| 789y | 2010-2 |
| 789y | 2010-4 |
| 323z | 2010-1 |
| 323z | 2010-5 |
| 323z | 2010-6 |

There are customers who have made one purchase, and customers who have made several.

I can count the number of times each customer has bought with:

```
df.groupby('customer_id').Count()
```

However, what I want to count is the number of times each value has been counted.
For example, if customer X has bought 2 times, customer Y has bought 2 times, and customer Z has bought 3 times, I want an output like this:

| Count | Repeated |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: .count().value_counts()?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry for my clumsiness, but when I create tables, although in the preview they turn out fine, when creating the post they come out in text format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `value_counts` twice:

```
df['customer_id'].value_counts().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
2    2
3    1
Name: Customer_ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can't believe it was as simple as that.
Thank you very much!